# Trying to get csv data to javascript array and getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

I have a validation in my site that uses a large table (in csv format).
I've tried the following code:

```
let styleurl = document.getElementById("isthisthestore");
      styleurl = styleurl.getAttribute("data-stylesheeturl")
      console.log(styleurl);
      let data;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: styleurl + "/tambour.csv",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(response)
          {
            data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
```

I'm getting the url from an element i have on the page (I'm sure therre is a better way but that's not the problem...)

I'm getting an error that says:"GET https://correct-file-url/tambour.csv 404"

Any idea why that is?

Comment: It means the source not found.

Comment: I understand it, but why?

Comment: Can you access https://correct-file-url/tambour.csv on your machine?

Comment: I have it in my cPanel, but as a url it doesn't work.
I need the file though, not a page...

Comment: If you cannot access the link in your machine, ofc, the ajax function cannot access it as well. You may find some API to fetch data from cPanel and you can access it through the API.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file for you see an easy code that work, but an observation is to check the complete "url", for example, when the var will printed on console, copy this url and check it, very important are that dont have any spaces white, or doubles slashs (//), see the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>An Example for correct csv.toArrays</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="isthisthestore" style="display: none;" data-id="https://yousiteweb.test/"> </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/1.0.11/jquery.csv.min.js" integrity="sha512-Y8iWYJDo6HiTo5xtml1g4QqHtl/PO1w+dmUpQfQSOTqKNsMhExfyPN2ncNAe9JuJUSKzwK/b6oaNPop4MXzkwg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
var styleurl = $('#isthisthestore').attr('data-id'); //use jquery to get an url
var styleurl = styleurl+"tambour.csv"; //dont put slashes in the file name if your var url have a slash in the end of string, like data-id="https://yoursiteweb.test/"


console.log('the complete url is: '+styleurl); // check if your url+file is available
let data;
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: styleurl, //the var with the csv file
          dataType: "html", //type html for use jquery.csv
          success: function(response)
          {
             data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

King Regards

Comment: Thank you for your help, you helped me find the issue, my url was incorrect.
the url i included had "/home3/sumsu000/public_html" , that i needed to remove...